# Class Z behaves like which well-known data structure?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am working with this question, which I am unsure about:

> Class Z behaves like which well-known data structure?

Where the possible answers is:

- A. (LIFO) Stack.
- B. (FIFO) Queue.
- C. Priority queue.
- D. Union–Find.

By looking at the code, I think the answer is D - union find. If we look at the methods query, last or first, we see it uses Union-find data-structure to determine if the array is equal or not.

```
public class Z
{
    int[] next, prev;

    Z(int N) {
        prev = new int[N];
        next = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i<N; ++i) {
            // put element i in a list of its own
            next[i] = i;
            prev[i] = i;
        }
    }

    int first(int i) {
        // return first element of list containing i
        while (i != prev[i]) i = prev[i];
        return i;
    }

    int last(int i) {
        // return last element of list containing i
        while (i != next[i]) i = next[i];
        return i;
    }

    void update(int i, int j) {
        int f = first(j);
        int l = last(i);
        next[l] = f;
        prev[f] = l;
    }

    boolean query(int i, int j) {
        return last(i) == last(j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right -- it can be used as a Union Find datastructure. If `z` is an instance of this class, then Union can be written as `if !z.query(i, j) z.update(i, j)`, and Find can be written `z.last(i)`.

### Details

`Z` keeps the integers `0, 1, ..., N-1`in a set of disjoint lists, with each integer in its own list initially. `update(i, j)` appends the list containing `j` to the list containing `i`. `first(i)` and `last(i)` return the first and last element of the list containing `i`. `query(i, j)` reports whether `i` and `j` are in the same list.

The implementation requires `update(i, j)` to only be called if `i` and `j` are not already in the same list (otherwise lists become loops, and subsequent calls to any of the methods may not terminate), and its efficiency is poor as the usual disjoint-union-datastructure optimizations aren't made.